# Puppet - undefined local variable

Tags: puppet

I'm getting undefined error but it is defined already. I'm sure this was working before (maybe in puppet 3) but I'm trying to use that code on puppet 6 (on a new server).

Any idea what is  the issue? Here is the error code:

```
 Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Failed to parse template resolv/resolv.conf.erb:\n 
 Filepath: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/resolv/templates/resolv.conf.erb\n  Line: 1\n  
 Detail: undefined local variable or method `domain' for #<Puppet::Parser::TemplateWrapper:0x60d6ba83>\n
```

Here is the code:

```
class resolv {
    case $hostname {
        /^[Abc]/: {
            resolv:resolv_config { 'Default':
                domain => "mydomain.local",
            }
        }
    }
}

define resolv::resolv_config($domain){
    file { '/etc/resolv.conf':
        content => template("resolv/resolv.conf.erb"),
    }
}
```

Here is the template content:

```
cat resolv.conf.erb

domain <%= domain %>
```

Comment: Are you expecting `$hostname` to be a fact, or some other kind of variable?

Comment: $hostname is from fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

All Puppet variables need to be prefixed with @ in Puppet 4+

So `resolv.conf.erb` should look like

```
domain <%= @domain %>
```